# lower bound in terms of symmetric functions

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Let $a_1,a_2,\cdots,a_n\in(0,1].$ Is there any best possible lower bound for $\sum_{m=1}^n \frac{1}{1+a_m}$ in the literature in terms of symmetric functions of $a_1,a_2,\cdots,a_n?$

i.e., is there any bound of the type $\sum_{m=1}^n \frac{1}{1+a_m}\geq f(b_1,b_2,\cdots,b_n)$ where $b_1=a_1+a_2+\cdots+a_n,$  $b_2=\sum_{i<j}a_ia_j,$  $b_3=\sum_{i<j<k}a_ia_ja_k$ ,...............,
$b_n=a_1.a_2.\cdots.a_n?$

Comment: Your sum *is* a symmetric function and can be written as the quotient of two polynomials in $b_i$. So you may want to be a bit more specific.